# Unable to execute command in the Linux with an user

Tags: linux, shell, command

Two scenarios here.

Sudo rights are given for a particular group.

a. A new user is created and is assigned to the group. b. Using this user, when we execute commands via shell script it is unable to execute any of the commands (eg., mkdir), it displays 'command not found' error.
but

a. When same command is executed in an open terminal it does execute and creates directories.
Any idea about the same would be greatly helpful.

Let me know if you need more information on this.

Comment: Why do you mention `sudo`? Sounds like a problem with the PATH to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the full path to the binary in your script; execute it with: `/bin/mkdir`
You can find the full paths to commands using `which` followed by the command.
It will then return the full path of the command e.g:

```
$ which mkdir
/bin/mkdir
```

You could also set PATH for the environment in which the script is run by using `export`. 
To do this in the script add a line similar to this: `export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin:/path/to/whateverelse` in the beginning of your script.

See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-adding-path/ for details.

Personally I would recommend just using the full path to binaries though.